# Plotting a circle on a Web map to view the resulting coverage over a central location

Tags: cartography, buffer

Not exactly a GIS question but I hope no one will mind.  Does anyone know of a website (something equivalent to Google Map) where you can indicate a location, give a radius and you can view the resulting coverage over that central location ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you're looking for:
http://www.freemaptools.com/radius-around-point.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is another useful site for getting similar information.

http://www.geomidpoint.com/destination/

Outputs a point which is based on bearing and distance from a given location. It generates the co-ordinates and also lets you view it in Google Maps. Doesn't generate the radius though, but has a potentially useful option of choosing based on Earth Model projection (though WGS84 elipsoid would be the most useful for the google webmap).